# Два проекта используют одинаковый Postgres датабазу, а проект на Django

Tags: django, postgresql, django-rest-framework, django-model

у меня есть два проекта которые используют одинаковый Postgresql датабазу. Один из этих проектов написано с Golang , а другой с Django. У меня задача в Django проекте взять данные с того таблицы который создается в другом проекте(на Golange). А точнее я должень взять данные с таблицы Clients который создается не в Django. Django проекте про эту  таблицу некого информации нет.

Внизу как я беру данные с таблицы Соок, который создается в Django проекте.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как я могу таким же образом взять данные с таблицы Клиентс?

Внизу оба репоситори проектов, и скиншоти из датабазы.

https://github.com/NarminSH/Go-Client.git

https://github.com/NarminSH/Lezzetly

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Этот вопрос я написал на английском тоже, с этими ответами я решил задачу.

You have a couple of options:

```
- Use Django's raw SQL queries to just SELECT data from that table
- Use inspectdb to have Django generate a model for the clients table. The model will have Meta.managed set to False, so Django won't touch it (e.g. do migrations). You can then use regular Django ORM operations for it.
- Manually write the model, setting db_table = "clients" and managed = False on the Meta class. You can then use regular Django ORM operations for it.
```

The model Django (or you) might generate could look something like